# Problem collecting the checkbox value using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

Am working on a form which has a checkbox input. The form has a checkbox input field whereby I change the value dynamically depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not. When the user clicks the checkbox the value should change to 1 ,,, when not clicked the value should be zero. Am collecting the value via AJAX and submitting to the backend (build in PHP Laravel),, when I dd() the value I get a null value of the checkbox,, please assist

**Layout containing the checkbox field**

```
 <div class="check-now {{ $errors->has('spouse') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" style="width: 100%;">
        <h1 class="cover-travel">I am travelling with</h1>
        <label class="spouse-me">
            <h1 class="pumba">Spouse</h1>
            <input type="checkbox" id="spouse" value="" class="spouse"  onClick="checkMark()">
        </label>
        @if ($errors->has('spouse'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('spouse') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
```

**Function that changes the checkbox value**

```
 function checkMark() {
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("spouse");
      var text = document.getElementById("spouseDetail");

      // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
      if (checkBox.checked == true){
        checkBox.value = '1';
      } else {
        checkBox.value = 'O';
      }
    }
```

**AJAX to submit data to backend**

```
// Get the form via its id
    var form = $('#travel_form');

    $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //alert('clicked');


        //Fetch the value of spouse
        var spouse = $('#spouse').val();

        //Log in console tab am getting an empty value
        console.log(spouse);

        //Add in a JS object
        var type = {
            'spouse' : spouse 
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getplans",
            data:JSON.stringify(type),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                window.location.href="getp" ;
            },
            //Alert errors from backend
            error: function(data) {
                var errors = '';
                for(datos in data.responseJSON){
                    errors += data.responseJSON[datos] + '\n';
                }
                alert(errors);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller handling the AJAX call**

```
 public
    function validatePlanEntries(Request $request)
    {   
        //dd($request->all());
    }
```

Comment: There's no need to change the value of a checkbox. When posting a form, if a checkbox isn't checked, it won't be submitted. It's like it doesn't exist and there for, the value of the checkbox is irrelevant. So basically, if you get the checkbox when you submit the form, it's checked.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I understood you,, the issue is I really need that checkbox value since am posting to an API

Comment: function checkMark() {
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("spouse");
      alert(checkBox); // what you getting here?

Comment: if (checkBox.checked == true){
        checkBox.value = '1';
alert(checkBox);
      } else {
        checkBox.value = 'O';
alert(checkBox);
      }

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Am using an if condition to check if the checkbox is checked,, change the value to 1 if not changed the default is zero

Comment: @Patweb but are you getting the values on those alert? I put inside your function or you are getting NaN there also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code quite a bit. If you just want to pass the state of the checkbox, you only need:

Instead of your `checkMark()` function, just check it in the submit callback.

```
// This will set the value 1 if it is checked and 0 if it isn't.
var checkBox = document.getElementById("spouse");
var type = {
    'spouse' : checkBox.checked ? 1 : 0 
}

// Don't stringify the object, just pass it as is. jQuery will take care if it.
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: type,
    ...
```